# PHP's exec() command not accepting a valid variable for execution

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using imagemagick and php together to process some words. I first break a sentence into words, then prepare those words for a long command line argument which I plan to call via PHP's exec() command. I have double-checked the argument; all characters are properly escaped including single and double quotes as per my knowledge. The exec() function does not work, saying `"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"`. But when I echo the `$escaped variable` and assign the echoed string to the php's exec(), it works without problem.

Here is the echoed string

```
exec("convert -background DeepSkyBlue -fill black -font Ultima-Alt-Bold.ttf -pointsize 90 -gravity center -density 90 label:\"SALIVA \" -fill black -font Ultima-Alt-Bold.ttf -pointsize 90 -gravity center -density 90 label:\"USED \" -fill black -font Ultima-Alt-Bold.ttf -pointsize 90 -gravity center -density 90 label:\"AS! \" +append Ulti.png"); // It works
```

The code I am using:

```
$file = 'theboldfont.ttf';
$name = substr($file, 0, 4);

$s = "SALIVA USED AS!";

$words = explode(' ',$s);
$string = '';

foreach ($words as $word) 
{
    $string .= " " . '-fill black -font ' . $file . ' -pointsize 90 -gravity center -density 90 label:"' . $word . ' "';  
}

$command = 'convert -background DeepSkyBlue ' . $string . ' +append ' . $name. '.png';  

function w32escapeshellarg($s)
{ return '"' . addcslashes($s, '\\"') . '"'; }

$escaped = w32escapeshellarg($command); 
exec($escaped); // It is not working
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the [PHP iMagick library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)? Calling native PHP functions should be more reliable than running `exec()` commands

Comment: check your php.ini file is imagemagick installed properly

Comment: @Saurabh, Yes, it is installed properly.

Comment: @Samlev, I know it is available. Ok, will think about it.

Comment: var dump your last line is it coming true

Comment: i think you should use `escapeshellarg` to escape your strings in the command. you have a lot of `\"` escaped quotes in your `$escaped` variable. this looks not right.

Comment: @Saurabh, when I var_dump I notice it is surrounded by an extra double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `escapeshellarg` to escape your strings:

```
<?php
$file = 'theboldfont.ttf';
$name = substr($file, 0, 4);

$s = "SALIVA USED AS!";

$words = explode(' ', $s);
$string = '';

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $string .= ' -fill black -font ' . escapeshellarg($file) . ' -pointsize 90 -gravity center -density 90 label:' . escapeshellarg($word);
}

$command = 'convert -background DeepSkyBlue ' . $string . ' +append ' . escapeshellarg($name . '.png');

exec($command);
```